# float sub navigation left

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a drop down navigation that you can see the sub menu within the drop down a little like this![enter image description here

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiRcq.png]

I have the essential layout i want though i am failing to actually create the drop down float left.

HTML

```
<div id='cssmenu'>

<ul>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Services</span></a>
   <div class="sub">
        <div class="subinner">
          <ul>
             <li><a href='#'><span>Consultancy</span></a></li>
             <li><a href='#'><span>Project Managment &amp; Execution</span></a></li>
             <li><a href='#'><span>Commissioning</span></a></li>
          </ul>

         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Plant Performance Enchancement</a></li>
        </ul>

        </div> <!-- End of Sub -->
      </div> <!-- End of Subinner -->
   </li>

   <li class='sub'><a href='#'><span>About</span></a>
    <div class="sub">
        <div class="subinner">
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Below is the CSS controls the drop down no JS is used.

```
#cssmenu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 7px 6px 0;
  background: #493B88;
  line-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
#cssmenu li {
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 0 0 8px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

#cssmenu a,
#cssmenu a:link {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #e7e5e5;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

#cssmenu a:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #000;
}

#cssmenu .active a,
#cssmenu li:hover > a {
  background: #ccc;
  color: #000;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li:hover a,
#cssmenu li:hover li a {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #000;
  width: 30%;
}

#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
  background: #7d7d7d;
  color: #000 !important;
  width: 400px;
}

#cssmenu li:hover > .sub .subinner ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

#cssmenu ul ul {
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: solid 1px #b4b4b4;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li {
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px;

}

#cssmenu ul ul a,
#cssmenu ul ul a:link {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

* html #cssmenu ul {
  height: 1%;
}
```

Here is a link to view my drop down menu Live
https://jsfiddle.net/pj8kL8dL/

Comment: Lets make it a bit more clear. You have services menu item. This one has 3 submenu items Train, PP and Ench. You want to float the box to the left or the 3 items side by side?

Comment: Yes that is correct as per the image linked in the question

Comment: Which on left? The box OR the 3 items?

Comment: If you look at the image i linked that is the essential layout i want the drop down to be left aligned and the sub menus to be within the drop down. left aligned as well displayed in line with each other.

Comment: Could you mark it as an answer? I spent so much time... Except if it was not an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have spent 2-3 hours to get this result, i hope it is what you need.

By the way, I would avoid using position:something so often.

It seems a responsive one, did you like the result?

```css
body{
 margin: 0;
}

#cssmenu ul {
  margin: 0;

}
#cssmenu ul > li {
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 0 0 8px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

#cssmenu ul > ul li {
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 0 0 8px;
  float: none;
  list-style: none;
}

#cssmenu a,
#cssmenu a:link {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #e7e5e5;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

#cssmenu a:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #000;
}

#cssmenu .active a,
#cssmenu li:hover > a {
  background: #ccc;
  color: #000;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li:hover a,
#cssmenu li:hover li a {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #000;
}

#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
  background: #7d7d7d;
  color: #000 !important;
}

#cssmenu li:hover > .sub .subinner ul {
  display: block;
}

#cssmenu ul ul {
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #b4b4b4;
  border-top: solid 1px #b4b4b4;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px;

}

#cssmenu li:nth-child(2) ul ul li {
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px;
}

#cssmenu li:nth-child(2) ul ul li a{

     border-bottom: 1px solid #B4B4B4;
}

#cssmenu ul ul a,
#cssmenu ul ul a:link {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

* html #cssmenu ul {
  height: 1%;
}

#cssmenu ul li:nth-child(2) .subinner{
 top: 47px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu ul li:nth-child(3) .subinner{
 top: 47px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu{
 
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 7px 6px 0px;
 background: #493B88 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
 line-height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 height: 40px;
}

#cssmenu li:nth-child(2):hover > .sub .subinner ul {
 width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu li:hover > .sub .subinner ul {
 width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu .subinner ul ul{
 float: left;
 width: 33% !important;
 border: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>

<ul>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Services</span></a>
   <div class="sub">
     <div class="subinner">
       <ul>
   <ul>
          <li><a href='#'><span>Consultancy</span></a></li>
          <li><a href='#'><span>Project Managment &amp; Execution</span></a></li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Commissioning</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><span>Training</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><span>Plant Performance Enchancement</span></a></li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
    <li><a href='#'><span>Something</span></a></li>
          <li><a href='#'><span>Something</span></a></li>
   </ul>
  </ul>

       </div> <!-- End of Sub -->
      </div> <!-- End of Subinner -->
   </li>

   <li class='sub'><a href='#'><span>About</span></a>
    <div class="sub">
     <div class="subinner">
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the layout i am looking for thank you for taking time on this though i want the same layout that is set on services on other drop downs i may set like about does not have the same layout

Edit: I Managed to get the same layout you have set a nth-child() I just removed it so that it applys globally to my nav thank you very much

Comment: @OnlineJordan I am happy that i helped, could you upvote my answer and mark is as the answer of your post? Edit: I did set nth-child just in case you wanted to give different values or do something else. Hope to see that my effort and time will give me some points by upvote and mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `position: relative;` in `#cssmenu li` so the sub menu will be relative to any outer div or `body`.

Also increase `width` of sub menu to 100% in `#cssmenu ul ul`